# Bash login script with zenity for CIFS mount

Tags: bash, login, scripts

I am writing a mount script for Windows share to run after login.
I have done it with bash and zenity and it works, but now I need to make it better so if username field and password field are empty then return to input.

Example

```
    wUsername=`zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Kasutajanimi:"`
#if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
#       exit 1
#fi
if [ -z "$wUsername" ]; then
        zenity --error --title="Viga kasutajanimes!" --text="Palun sisestage oma kasutajanimi"


# get the windows password
wPassword=`zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Parool:" --hide-text`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        exit 1
fi
```

So I want this script to trow user back to input if ***Kasutajanimi*** aka username or ***Parool*** aka password is empty. Even if space is pressed.

I have searched the all mighty Google for it and I know I can do it with return somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Define a function that launches the zenity username dialog
get_username(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Kasutajanimi:" 
}
## Define a function that launches the zenity password dialog
get_password(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Parool:" --hide-text
}

## Attempt to get the username and exit if cancel was pressed.
wUsername=$(get_username) || exit

## If the username is empty or matches only whitespace.
## See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html
## for an explanation of this syntax. The . means any non-space
## character so when this is less than 1, the username is empty
## or just whitespace. Since this is a while loop, the process
## will be repeated until the username is correctly submitted.
while [ "$(expr match "$wUsername" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Viga kasutajanimes!" --text="Palun sisestage oma kasutajanimi"
    wUsername=$(get_username) || exit
done

## Same as the previous loop but for the password. Sorry if
## the message is wrong, I don't speak this language :)
wPassword=$(get_password) || exit

while [ "$(expr match "$wPassword" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Viga Parool!" --text="Palun sisestage oma Parool"
    wPassword=$(get_password) || exit
done
```

Comment: But if the user wants to press Cancel it does not let him cancel the login after I tested empty username or password cancel button does not work. Gives me the zenity error. Would it work if I added else exit to while loop?

Comment: @user2021157 yes, sorry, I fixed it now. See updated answer, you do indeed need the `|| exit` inside the loop as well.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
# ask for username
while true # start infinity loop
do
    wUsername=`zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Kasutajanimi:"`

    # user abort
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          exit 0
    fi

    # remove spaces
    wUsername=$( echo "$wUsername" | tr -d ' ' )

    # check user input
    if [ -z "$wUsername" ]; then
        # user input is empty -> throw error and continue the loop
        zenity --error --title="Viga kasutajanimes!" --text="Palun sisestage oma kasutajanimi"  
    else # user input is not empty 
        break # leave loop
    fi
done
```

and the same for the password input.

Comment: This is good as well, but terdon's one is more suitable for me, but this works as well. :)